# How to implement react-native-material-bottom-navigation with React Native Router Flux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-router-flux

I'm trying to implement [react-native-material-bottom-navigation](https://github.com/timomeh/react-native-material-bottom-navigation) component with React Native Router Flux.

I've tried to use this component with RNRF but it doesn't work as I expect it should do it.

I placed the BottomNavigation in each screen but every time I click a tab it reloads everything. I think the BottomNavigation should be in the Router of my app but I've not figured out how to mix this components to work together.

I used to use the onPress inside the tab but it doesn't work and as *timomeh* says in an issue ([#79](https://github.com/timomeh/react-native-material-bottom-navigation/issues/79)) in the repository, I should use `onTabChange` instead `onPress`.

In the Bottom Navigation component docs I read an "usage" for React-navigation and I know RNRF is based on React-navigation but I've not achieved what I want.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Right now that's not supported out of the box with `react-navigation-router-flux` - but it's possible to be added. I have added the support for the deprecated tab bar a few weeks ago - and almost added this - but since it was going to add an extra dependency, I decided to keep it out. Please, open an issue in the repo with the details - so people can discuss more about it - and maybe that can be added in a way that the dependency might be better handled.